# Component image file in React Static Boilerplate

Tags: reactjs

1. Where is the ideal location to put image file (.jpg, .png) in [react static boilerplate](http://react%20static%20boilerplate)
2. How to use them inside component?

Answer (score 0):

Usually static files, images etc are stored inside `./public/` folder. It would be better if you store the images inside that folder. You can use another separate folder inside `./public/` folder, like `images`.

---

It is pretty clear if you have gone through the documentation page. Here is the folder structure. Please see the portion that is in bold.

```
.
├── /components/                # Shared or generic UI components
│   ├── /Button/                # Button component
│   ├── /Layout/                # Website layout component
│   ├── /Link  /                # Link component to be used instead of <a>
│   └── /...                    # etc.
├── /core/                      # Core framework
│   ├── /history.js             # Handles client-side navigation
│   ├── /router.js              # Handles routing and data fetching
│   └── /store.js               # Application state manager (Redux)
├── /node_modules/              # 3rd-party libraries and utilities
├── /pages/                     # React components for web pages
│   ├── /about/                 # About page
│   ├── /error/                 # Error page
│   ├── /home/                  # Home page
│   └── /...                    # etc.
├── /public/                    # Static files such as favicon.ico etc.*
│   ├── /dist/                  # The folder for compiled output
│   ├── favicon.ico             # Application icon to be displayed in bookmarks
│   ├── robots.txt              # Instructions for search engine crawlers
│   └── /...                    # etc.
├── /test/                      # Unit and integration tests
├── /utils/                     # Utility and helper classes
│── main.js                     # React application entry point
│── package.json                # The list of project dependencies and NPM scripts
│── routes.json                 # This list of application routes
│── run.js                      # Build automation script, e.g. `node run build`
└── webpack.config.js           # Bundling and optimization settings for Webpack
```